# Android Studio building release apk fails

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, windows-10

This is for android studio 2.2.3 with windows 10.

When building the release apk for my app gradle fails.

When building the debug apk everything works fine.

I have reinstalled android studio. I also rebuild the project and clean the build quite a bit.

I have tried changing versions of dependencies.
Using built in java jdk, and current java jdk from oracle.
Changing jackOptions enable to true, and false.
Minified enabled and sip align enabled true and false.
Altering my proguard file.
Using different sizes for heap.
I have closed Android studio and deleted .gradle from main project directory and opened the project again and rebuilt it.

I notice in gradle console that the Executing java process keeps restarting. Not sure if this matters, and right before that line it states StoredItem is null. Both have the info tag.

I have been having this issue for weeks, I have searched all over the internet.

Here is the stack trace.

```
Error:23:04:00.648 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:04:00.648 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
23:04:00.648 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:04:00.649 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:04:00.649 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':askGodWhy:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForFreeRelease'.
23:04:00.649 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)
23:04:00.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:04:00.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
23:04:00.654 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':askGodWhy:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForFreeRelease'.
23:04:00.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
23:04:00.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
23:04:00.663 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
23:04:00.664 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
23:04:00.671 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
23:04:00.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
23:04:00.681 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
23:04:00.696 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
23:04:00.704 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
23:04:00.704 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
23:04:00.704 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
23:04:00.704 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
23:04:00.705 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
23:04:00.705 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
23:04:00.705 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
23:04:00.705 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
23:04:00.705 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
23:04:00.705 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
23:04:00.706 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
23:04:00.706 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
23:04:00.707 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
23:04:00.707 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
23:04:00.708 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
23:04:00.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
23:04:00.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
23:04:00.709 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
23:04:00.710 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
23:04:00.711 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
23:04:00.711 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
23:04:00.748 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
23:04:00.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
23:04:00.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
23:04:00.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
23:04:00.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
23:04:00.749 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
23:04:00.753 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
23:04:00.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
23:04:00.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
23:04:00.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
23:04:00.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
23:04:00.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
23:04:00.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
23:04:00.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
23:04:00.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
23:04:00.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
23:04:00.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
23:04:00.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
23:04:00.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
23:04:00.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
23:04:00.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
23:04:00.768 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
23:04:00.768 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
23:04:00.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
23:04:00.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
23:04:00.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
23:04:00.769 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.771 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
23:04:00.771 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
23:04:00.771 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
23:04:00.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:04:00.772 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
23:04:00.773 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
23:04:00.773 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
23:04:00.773 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
23:04:00.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
23:04:00.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessInfoBuilder$JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable(ProcessInfoBuilder.java:349)
23:04:00.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
23:04:00.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
23:04:00.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCodeUsingJackCli(AndroidBuilder.java:1834)
23:04:00.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCodeUsingJack(AndroidBuilder.java:1645)
23:04:00.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.JackConversionCache.convertLibrary(JackConversionCache.java:99)
23:04:00.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.JackPreDexTransform.runJack(JackPreDexTransform.java:174)
23:04:00.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.JackPreDexTransform.transform(JackPreDexTransform.java:119)
23:04:00.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
23:04:00.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
23:04:00.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
23:04:00.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 70 more
23:04:00.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Here is my global gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        try {
            Release_KeyStore {
                keyAlias 'release_keystore'
                storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
                keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
                storeFile file('Path_to_Release_Keystore.jks')
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("You should define KEYSTORE_PASSWORD and KEY_PASSWORD in gradle.properties.")
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "MyAppId"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.Release_KeyStore
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"MyApp"'
        resValue 'string', 'app_directory', '"MyAppDirectory"'
        resValue 'string', 'banner_ad_unit_id', BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID
        resValue 'string', 'interstitial_ad_unit_id', INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID
        resValue 'string', 'environment', ENVIRONMENT_RELEASE

        jackOptions {
            enabled false
            jackInProcess false
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
        jumboMode = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"MyApp"'
            resValue 'string', 'app_directory', '"MyAppDirectory"'
            resValue 'string', 'banner_ad_unit_id', BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_TEST
            resValue 'string', 'interstitial_ad_unit_id', INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_TEST
            resValue 'string', 'environment', ENVIRONMENT_DEBUG

            jackOptions {
                enabled false
                jackInProcess false
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Release_KeyStore
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"MyApp"'
            resValue 'string', 'app_directory', '"MyAppDirectory"'
            resValue 'string', 'banner_ad_unit_id', BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID
            resValue 'string', 'banner_ad_unit_id', INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID
            resValue 'string', 'environment', ENVIRONMENT_RELEASE

            jackOptions {
                enabled false
                jackInProcess false
            }
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "MyAppId"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 6
            versionName "1.0.6"
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Release_KeyStore
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"MyApp"'
            resValue 'string', 'app_directory', '"MyAppDirectory"'
            resValue 'string', 'banner_ad_unit_id', BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID
            resValue 'string', 'interstitial_ad_unit_id', INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID
            resValue 'string', 'some_key', SOME_KEY
            resValue 'string', 'environment', ENVIRONMENT_RELEASE
        }
        paid {
            applicationId "MyAppId"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 6
            versionName "1.0.6"
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Release_KeyStore
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', '"MyApp"'
            resValue 'string', 'app_directory', '"MyAppDirectory"'
            resValue 'string', 'some_key', SOME_KEY
            resValue 'string', 'environment', ENVIRONMENT_RELEASE
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res/layouts/pages',
                           'src/main/res/layouts/components',
                           'src/main/res/layouts',
                           'src/main/res'
            ]
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
task debug << {
    configurations.compile.each { println it }
}
// only needed for SNAPSHOT builds
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}
dependencies {
    //compile project(':library')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.6'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.6'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
    compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
        // workaround issue #73
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
}
```

Here is my proguard file.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; 
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** { *; }

#All my Dto classes for serializing and de-serializing service requests.
-keep public class MyDtoClasses.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
}

-keep class okhttp3.** { *; } 
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; } 
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-optimizationpasses 5
-printmapping map.txt
-flattenpackagehierarchy
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.PreferenceActivity
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.widget.BaseAdapter
-keep public class * implements android.view.View.OnTouchListener

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontobfuscate
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn javax.mail.**
-dontwarn javax.naming.Context
-dontwarn javax.naming.InitialContext
-dontwarn junit.framework.TestCase
-dontwarn junit.framework.TestSuite
-dontwarn junit.runner.BaseTestRunner
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
```

Let me know if I need to provide any thing else.

Comment: I think the problem is of .jar file in your project. you have  jackrabbit-standalone-2.12.2.jar this jar file in your project?

Comment: your minSdkVersion is 24 and some of your .jar file uses old version thats why this problem takes place

Comment: I removed all jars from my project, do you see that reference somewhere?It was 16 and i changed it to 24 when i got some errors after changing to the newest version of java.

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-how-to-handle-unsupportedoperationexception/

Comment: packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
} try this

Comment: I also put my java back to what is built in for android studio and moved the minsdk back to 16, I got the same error with the built in java and min sdk to 16, with @Zaki suggestion I get the same error.

Comment: still same error?

Comment: Yes. Same error as before @Zaki.

Comment: once try with this change. minifyEnabled false. So we got something if this works for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41145498/7320259 same problem please check

Comment: I use the rebuild project quite a bit, i have also cleaned many times before, but i will try again after this build. @Zaki Pathan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135822/discussion-between-zaki-pathan-and-elijah123467).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks @Zaki for all your help.

I moved my solution to a newer computer and received more errors to work with, like my code is using java.util libraries that only work for api 24 and above.

I switched my android studio to use the packaged java 8 version.

When I switched to java 8 I had added the jack enabled and version to 8, but this broke everything for a release build.

I then switched this from true to false.

```
jackOptions {
                enabled false
            }
```

I then set this from 8 to 7.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

As long as your code and the libraries you include in your project will work for java 7, your code should build for release.